# Control view of Multi polygon in Google map

Tags: polygon, google-maps

We have multipolygon WKT. We have no issue to draw all of them in Google map.
Below are the codes. The only issue is that we want only the first polygon to be visible but the rest to transparent. How to control on that? Any idea please?

```
function drawPoly(data, pl) {
    var pointsData = data.split(",");
    var cords = [];

    // iterate over each points data and create a latlong
    // & add it to the cords array
    var len = pointsData.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var xy = pointsData[i].split(" ");

        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(xy[1], xy[0]);
        cords.push(pt);
    }

    // now add it to the map
    // Construct the polygon
    alert("I=" + pl);
    var polygonFirst = "";
    if (pl == 0) {
        var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths : cords,
            strokeColor : '#1E90FF',
            strokeOpacity : 0.8,
            strokeWeight : 2,
            fillColor : '#1E90FF',
            fillOpacity : 0.35,
            zIndex : 1
        });
        // polygon1.setMap(map);
    } else {
        var polygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
            paths : cords,
            strokeColor : '#1122AA',
            strokeOpacity : 1,
            strokeWeight : 2,
            zIndex : 1
        });
        // polygon2.setZIndex(1);
        polygon2.setMap(map);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Tamas: i used your code and got a problem, because the coordinates of the multipolygone hasn't the right order: [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tVHON.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tVHON.png) the reason is the following snippet: `... = multipolygonWKT.replace("))", "");` Without that, i got the right order. Maybe, this could be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just put together the following function. I hope it will help you! It return an array of the polylines contained in the multipolygon with the first styled to your requirements. Please let me know if this was useful to you! p.s.: You will have to set the map property of the polylines later, as the resulting polylines do not have their map property set to your map in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

    function drawPoly(multipolygonWKT){
        var polylines = [];
        var toReturn = [];

        var formattedValues = multipolygonWKT.replace("))", "");
             formattedValues = formattedValues.replace("((", "");


        var linesCoords = formattedValues.split("),(");



        for(i=0;i<linesCoords.length;i++){
            polylines[i] = [];
            var singleLine = linesCoords[i].split(",");

            for(j=0;j<singleLine.length;j++){
                var coordinates = singleLine[j].split(" ");
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coordinates[1]), parseFloat(coordinates[0]));

                polylines[i].push(latlng);

            }
        }

    //by now you should have the polylines array filled with arrays that hold the coordinates of the polylines of the multipolyline
    //lets loop thru this array

    for(k=0;k<polylines.length;k++){
        var line = polylines[k];
        if(k==0){
            toReturn.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                paths: line,
                                                strokeColor: '#FF00FF',
                                                strokeOpacity: 0,
                                                strokeWeight: 6,
                                                fillColor: '#1E90FF',
                                                fillOpacity: 0,
                                                zIndex:1                                                        
            }));
        }
        else if(k>0)
        {
            toReturn.push(
                new google.maps.Polygon({
                                                paths: line,
                                                strokeColor: '#1122AA',
                                                strokeOpacity: 1,
                                                strokeWeight: 2,                                                   
                                                zIndex:1    
                })                                    
            );
        }
    }
    return toReturn;
    }   


     $(document).ready(function(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(47, 19),
            zoom:6,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        var mps = ["MULTIPOLYGON((4 47,19.1 50.1,18.1 60,4 47),(3.9 46.9,28.5 46.5,5 30,3.9 46.9))", "MULTIPOLYGON((50 57,20.1 47.1,1 1,50 57),(11.9 46.9,31.5 46.5,50 1,11.9 46.9))"];
        for(i in mps){
            var lines = drawPoly(mps[i].replace("MULTIPOLYGON",""));
            for(k=0;k<lines.length;k++){
                lines[k].setMap(map);
            }
            lines.length = 0;
        }                           
     });
    </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="height:600px;width:600px;" id="map"></div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: @I tried your codes but no shapes are appearing and there is an error in the else part it should be line for the paths I managed all that ready. Now what should I do is it due to the toReturn where it suppose to go?

Comment: I have edited the code I put together yesterday since it had a couple of typos as i put it together quickly. This one above should work as expected.You can just copy and paste to a new file and try it in your browser.

Comment: Hi what I need actually is the first K=0 polygon will be normally the biggest one. Then the rest should be able to like create holes in the bigger one. In this case when the first fillOpacity: 1 only the small ones appear. So how create hole effect?

Comment: Hi Tamas I found some are talking here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504788/google-maps-polygons-overlay . So I want the hole effect by the rest of the smaller polygon. I dont know to work this on my little polygon.

Comment: This link I found there is very useful: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_polygon_example_donut.html The order of the polygons are up to you, how you order them in your WKT string. Was my code helpful to you anyways?

Comment: Your codes could not create the hole effect.So how to create the hole effect for the polygon above index 1 ? MY problem now I dont know how to reorder my polygon? Any idea on that  ?

Comment: How do geometries get recorded to your atabase from which you fetch the WKT strings?

Comment: Mine is generated in via the google drawing tools then I combine all the lat long into a the standard wKT for e.g. POLYGON((100.909423828125 4.784468966579362,101.337890625 4.543570279371759,101.019287109375 4.521666342614804,100.931396484375 4.532618393971778,100.909423828125 4.784468966579362,100.909423828125 4.784468966579362))

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9077/discussion-between-tamas-and-biz14)

Comment: It cant move there it say I got not enough reputation?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mps = ["MULTIPOLYGON(82.089844 38.839708,81.12304 37.492214,83.078613 37.788081,82.089844 38.839708)","MULTIPOLYGON(50 57,20.1 47.1,1 1,50 57)", "MULTIPOLYGON(82.150269 38.668356,82.29309 38.858959,82.150269 38.668356)"];

        for (i in mps) {
            //var lines = drawPoly(mps[i].replace("MULTIPOLYGON", ""));
            var boundarydata = new Array();
            var lines = (mps[i].replace("MULTIPOLYGON", ""));
            var formattedValues = lines.replace(")", "");
            formattedValues = formattedValues.replace("(", "");


            var linesCoords = formattedValues.split(",");

            var latlongs = formattedValues.split(",");

                for (var i = 0; i < latlongs.length; i++) {
                    latlong = latlongs[i].trim().split(" ");
                    boundarydata[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(latlong[1], latlong[0]);
                }

                boundaryPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
                            path: boundarydata,
                            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                            strokeWeight: 2,
                            fillColor: 'Red',
                            fillOpacity: 0.4

                        });
                        map.setCenter(boundarydata[0]);
                        boundaryPolygon.setMap(map);


            lines.length = 0;
```